# Content types determined automatically on server-side, but how?

Tags: java, playframework, mime-types, content-type

My browser is sending `application/octet-stream`.

But on the server side I have a correct `Content-Type` header mime value.
After some tests I concluded it is based on the file extension like `.txt` or `.pdf`.

Where is the mapping done usually, does it rely on the operating system for this ? How should servers behave ?

For Java I found this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29

> If the file is recognized then the content type is returned. If the file is not recognized by any of the installed file type detectors then a system-default file type detector is invoked to guess the content type.

Comment: The server is likely "guessing" what the content type is. Though it really depends on the implementation. It could be using the system, or it might have an internal database of known file types.

Comment: I know it is guessing based on the extension, but I have no idea how this is achieved. I suspect it could be based on the OS.